# Get Facebook group posts without being an admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get all the posts from a **public group** on facebook without the graph api/group api?
I am a member in the group but I'm not an admin so I don't have the permissions to do it with the formal facebook api.
But I can access all the data with my browser so I can see all the posts throw the web GUI.. So I thought there's might be a way to download/get all the posts from a group without the need to be an admin..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all the posts from a public group on facebook without the graph api/group api?

Circumventing the APIs would not be allowed to begin with; you *have to* use those, if you want to gather any data by any automated means, everything else would be against the ToS.

There is no way to access group posts via API, if an admin does not “install” your app in the group first.
The group visibility does not matter in that regard, it is the same for private or public.